# How To Use Triangle Operators In Pattern Matching Function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, sequence, parse-error

I'm trying to use Sequences to improve performance. When defining the function below I tried to use the "triangle" operators in pattern patching context.

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

cleanField :: S.Seq Char -> S.Seq Char
cleanField ((S.<|)  ' '  xs) = cleanField xs
cleanField ((S.|>)  xs  ' ') = cleanField xs
cleanField  xs = xs
```

GHC 7.4.1 says:

```
seq.hs:4:13: Parse error in pattern: (S.<|)
```

Can I not use the triangle operators (`<|`,`|>`)in pattern matching?

If so, why can I use the cons (`:`) operator in pattern matching and not the triangle operators?

Comment: I am not familiar with that module, but perhaps `<|` et al are not constructors, are they? You may use `:` in a pattern because it's a constructor.

Comment: @XavierPinho They appear to be [constructors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#g:1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xavier Pinho is correct. The operators `(<|)` and `(|>)` are ordinary functions, but only data constructors may be used in patterns. (Yes, they're listed in the docs under the title *Construction*, because they're used to construct sequences out of components, but they're not technically data constructors.)

The library offers two functions `viewl` and `viewr` to create members of datatypes `ViewL` and `ViewR`. These have constructors `:<` and `:>` that can be matched on.

An example:

```
s :: Seq Int
s = fromList [1,2,3]

test1 :: (Int, Seq Int)
test1 = case viewl s of
          x :< xs -> (x, xs)

test2 :: (Seq Int, Int)
test2 = case viewr s of
          xs :> x -> (xs, x)
```

The views are also convenient to use with the `ViewPatterns` language extension. If enabled, you can say

```
test3 :: Seq Int -> (Int, Seq Int)
test3 (viewl -> x :< xs) = (x, xs)
```

to match on an incoming sequence as if it was a list.

Answer (score 7):

You can only pattern match on constructors and infix constructors in Haskell have to start with a colon. So those triangle operators are normal functions, `:` is a list constructor.

To inspect one end of a `Sequence`, you can use the `viewl` and `viewr` functions. These return a `ViewL` and `ViewR`, respectively, and these types also have triangle-like operators as constructors. You could use them as follows with pattern guards.

```
cleanField xs
  | ' '  S.:< rest <- S.viewl xs = cleanField rest
  | rest S.:> ' '  <- S.viewr xs = cleanField rest
  | otherwise                    = xs
```

Comment: Is the starting with a colon (`:`) thing a compiler enforced language rule or a implementer enforce language convention?

Comment: @awashburn It's a part of the language. The compiler treats all lowercase or normal symbolic names as variables in patterns, and uppercase or symbolic names with an initial `:` as data constructors. You got an error because you used a qualified variable name which is illegal in a pattern.